# Rails Many to Many Filter Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails app and I have a model called "Component" which represents the components that make up a system I look after. I'd like to create filters to display only certain subsets of these components.

I've created a many to many relationship between the "Component" and "Filter" models. I'd like to set up a form for editing the filters that displays all of the components with check boxes next to them to indicate whether the filter should display these components. A component may be visible in many filters hence many to many.

I'm relatively new to Ruby/Rails so I'm not really sure how to do this, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by watching this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple

Once you've got an idea about how to setup these kind of forms, flip through this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/calamitas/restful-best-practices

That'll help give you some ideas about how your resources may need to be set up. You probably want to think about having a has_many :through relationship so you get a proper join model, something like ComponentFilters.

Then you have a ComponentFilters controller, and your edit view can create a table with components on one axis, filters on the other, and checkboxes for each combination. Those checkboxes should be setup to send the id of the filter and the component you're associating -- ie creating a NEW ComponentFilter record.

I hope this gives you a start on how to think about it. As you progress through if you have more specific questions come back and ask them :)

Comment: Thanks! That really helped and I've got it working how I want now :D